# Не получается создать файл записей

Tags: pascalabc.net

Пытаюсь создать типизированный файл из записей, но тут  выскакивает ошибка:

> records.pas(9):Типизированый файл не может содержать элементы такого типа

Ранее этот же код запускался в turbopascal'е и работал, так в чем же ошибка?!

```
program cheat_for_copatel;
type
  someone=record
  name,lst_name,batya,birth,addres:string;
  end;
var
  otpt_human,inpt_human:someone;
  i:integer;
  Fvar:file of someone;
begin
assign(Fvar, 'data.txt');
reset(Fvar);
writeln(0);
end.
```

Comment: `:string;` -> `:shortstring;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строки `string` - это ссылочный тип. В Вашей структуре - пять указателей. Это не то, что следует сохранять в файл. Используйте `shortstring` или `string[Ваша длина]`. Ограничение: максимальная длина таких строк - 255.